# How can I make an helper function - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I add another function to **auth()**

Example :

```
auth()->id(),auth()->user()....
```

I want to add another job like this

```
auth()->seller(),auth()->author() ...
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: you can define function in `User` Model and then you can use as `auth()->user()->seller()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use macro in Laravel to register methods and inject them.

```
SessionGuard::macro('seller', function () {
            return \Auth::user()->seller;
});
```

Thus it will work `auth()->seller()`

Comment: What would be the suiteable place to register macros? In a `ServiceProvider`?

Comment: In AppServiceProvider  register method.